# Is it possible to save snapshots from multiple video streams using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I would like to periodically save a snapshot from a video stream using ffmpeg. This is is possible using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i [source] -r 0.2 -f image2 ./image-%04d.jpeg`

or the (rough) equivalent in ffmpge-python:

```py
ffmpeg.input(source, **inputArgs)
    .filter("fps", fps=1 / 5, round="up")
    .output("./image-%04d.jpeg")
```

I would like to do this for N input streams simultaneously. So, I would be saving 1 frame every 5 seconds for each of the input streams. Is this possible using ffmpeg or ffmpeg-python? I can't find any examples with multiple input streams.

Just for some more information: the sources are all rtsp streams and N can be between 10 and 60. I also would like to limit the number of files on disk at any one time (similar to G-streamer's [max-files](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/multifilesink.html?gi-language=c#multifilesink:max-files) property) but this is less important.

Comment: You can use my script Just create a list of rtsp sources and Loop over Them. https://github.com/Cacsjep/pyrtsputils/blob/main/snapshot_generator.py

Comment: With the `video.demux()` and then `packet.decode()` setup I seem to be getting a lot of `ERROR:libav.hevc:PPS changed between slices.` errors. Do you know what causes this/how I can fix it? It's intermittently able to save some snapshots to disk but not consistently.

Comment: In video encoding, PPS stands for Picture Parameter Set. It's a set of parameters used to define the properties of a series of pictures (frames) within a video. These parameters include aspects like slice group mapping, weighted prediction, and intra prediction modes.

The error message suggests that the PPS is changing between slices within a single frame or across frames, which is not standard behavior. A "slice" in video encoding refers to a part of a picture (frame) that is encoded and decoded independently.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `run_async()`. From the docs:

> Asynchronously invoke ffmpeg for the supplied node graph.

https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/index.html#ffmpeg.run_async

This creates a subprocess which runs FFMPEG concurrently with your Python program. You can then call `run_async()` multiple times.

Danger note: if you use `pipe_stdin`, `pipe_stdout`, or `pipe_stderr`, be aware that this will cause your FFMPEG processes to freeze if you do not call `process.communicate()` on each subprocess occasionally to drain their output pipes.